# SQL | Get row from table where I have parent and child nodes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table with both parent and child nodes.

Table:

| ID | Parent | Child | Level | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | NULL | 10 | 1 | Level 1 |
| 200 | 10 | 20 | 2 | Level 2 |
| 300 | 20 | 30 | 3 | Level 3 |
| 400 | 30 | 40 | 4 | Level 4 |
| 101 | NULL | 11 | 1 | Lvl 1 |
| 201 | 11 | 21 | 2 | Lvl 2 |

From another query I get a row with the information related to the last level of my table. For example:

| ID | Field1 | Field2 | Parent | Child | Level | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 456 | 30 | 40 | 4 | Level 4 |

I need to get the information related to the other levels. I want to get a result set like:

| ID | Field1 | Field2 | Level | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 456 | 4 | Level 4 |
| 1 | 123 | 456 | 3 | Level 3 |
| 1 | 123 | 456 | 2 | Level 2 |
| 1 | 123 | 456 | 1 | Level 1 |

Important: I never know how many levels there are for each case. Also, I only get the values of Field1 and Field2 for the last level.

Comment: Anytime I have parent to child relationships, and don't want to write programming in a backend language to sort them, I use a relational set of tables (Usually 3 tables) -- EAV setup if you will  ..  Entity (Your Main object identified by ID) -- Attribute (In this case Child/Parent) -- Value (In this case Level 1, Level 2, Level 3, Level 4).  Then use a basic `JOIN` statement to get the result set desired.  It's a little more complicated to set up, but you'll thank yourself that you don't have to write complicated queries to get the result set you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive `cte` to walk the tree from a given level to the root:

```
with recursive cte as (
   select t.* from tbl t where t.level = 4
   union all
   select t.* from cte c join tbl t on t.child = c.parent
)
select f.id, f.field1, f.field2, c.level, c.description 
from cte c cross join fields f where f.level = 4
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc1f5a6cd27a0782b476c9fa42d8d744).